# Change music file Balance

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, avaudioplayer

Is there any way to change a music file Balance?
for example I want to play a sound only from left speaker(by default my sound file is playing in both speaker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to manipulate the sound at all, openAL is probably better. It's definitely faster to check the documentation of AVAudioPlayer and use the pan property, but openAL allows pan, gain, location, and balance, along with effects.

Answer (score 5):

you should be able to control the so called panorama with setting the property 'pan' of your avaudioplayer instance.

look in the [documentation for AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)... should be simple.

good luck